# Is there any good design pattern or solution to handle the transition behavior having a dependency between states?

Tags: design-patterns

Suppose there are four states like below.

```
A state
B state
C state
D state
```

And there is a complex transition dependency like below.

```
A is default state
B is C,D state's precondition
C is D state's precondition
```

Currently, my idea is the following.

```
if(conditionXXX){
 state = B;
}
else if(B && conditionYYY) {
 state = C;
}
else if(C && conditionZZZ) {
 state = D;
}
else {
 state = A;
}
```

But I'm considering that is not a nice solution.
Is there any good design pattern or a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever paradigm you choose, what you probably want in this case is modularity of states (I'm not using encapsulation on purpose). That means that each state should be reasonably self-contained, and in this case, only know about some sort of ID of the state to transition to, as well with the conditions.

We can model that in many ways, but typically it's best to start with the simplest, most direct approach.

```
type StateId = String
type Transition = Context -> Maybe StateId
data State = State { transition :: Transition, action :: Action, id :: StateId }
```

In this case, I'm not providing the types for `Action` and `Context` because they ultimately depend on how you want to get your `conditionXXX/YYY/ZZZ` and what do you want to do when in a given state.

The type of `Transition` means that each state needs to provide some logic that determines whether it can move to another state.

Expressing your logic, that would be:

```
stateA = State { transition = \ctx -> if conditionXXX ctx then Just "B" else Nothing, action = (), id = "A" }

stateB = State { transition = \ctx -> if conditionYYY ctx then Just "C" else Nothing, action = (), id = "B" }

stateC = State { transition = \ctx -> if conditionZZZ ctx then Just "D" else Nothing, action = (), id = "C" }

stateD = State { transition = Just "A", action = (), id = "D" }
```

Note that you don't have to check which state you're in, as it's implied by the fact that those functions reside within the State value.

Armed with that, we just need to store the states:

```
data StateMachine = StateMachine { states :: [State], currentState :: State }

sm = StateMachine [stateA, stateB, stateC, stateD] stateA
```

Now the transformation function needs to be able to be able to ask the current state whether it can transition:

```
transition :: Context -> StateMachine -> StateMachine
transition context sm = 
    case transition (currentState sm) $ context of
        Nothing -> sm
        Just newStateId -> {- find the State associated with id and change currentState }
```

I chose Haskell for this example implementation, but you can of course write this in any language. They key idea is that the collection of states is open from the perspective of `transition` and `StateMachine`, and you can freely add and remove them to the machine.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.
If explain were c++ language, I would have been easy to understand for me.
If you know similar c++ example about this, please let me know :)